# ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol exception after test connection in OBIEE 11g

Tags: oracle11g, obiee, oracle19c

Our current set up is OBIEE 11g connected to Oracle 11g database. We have currently upgraded our oracle 11g DB to 19c. We're trying to connect our OBIEE 11g to 19c db but we are getting an error that says "ORA-28040: No matching authentication protocol exception". This the current driver we are using: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Addjq.jpg

Here's the error: [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMSnT.jpg

What do we need to do? Do we need to update our drivers?

Thank you so much in advance.

Regards,
ICD

Comment: What is the exact version of the 11g client and database, and what are the `COMPATIBILE` initialization parameter values for each database?

Comment: In addition: Why are you trying to use ODBC to connect to the DB? Oracle data connections always go over OCI. Not ODBC.

Comment: Hi @pmdba, our exact 11g client version is 11.2.0.3.0 and database Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production. Do we need to install updated drivers in order to connect to oracle 19c? And no we are using OCI.

Comment: Different OCI client versions support different authentication protocols - essentially different hashing algorithms for the passwords. The `COMPATIBLE` parameter in the database determines which client versions are supported by default when a password is set. What is the setting of the `COMPATIBLE` parameter in your 19c database?

Answer (score 0):

It could be the JDBC driver version. See MOS Doc ID 2532847.1 (https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=2532847.1).

Note, if you update the JDBC driver to a higher version, you may also have to update your JDK is you're not using JDK 7 or higher.

Comment: Hi @Chuck B, no we are not using any JDBC drivers. We are using ODBC drivers.